# Error with Server SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, html, json

### Explanation

I am having problems with a JSON file which message appears ***"Error with Server SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1"*** I have been reviewing the file and checked the encoding of this and no apparent results, it seems that there is some kind of syntax configuration error but I can not find it.

### Code.

```
const joking = {};
joking.localstate = {};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startup);

function startup() {
    joking.username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    joking.gamename = localStorage.getItem('gamename');

    const domApp = window.app;
    domApp.innerHTML = '';

    window.topBar.innerHTML = renderCurrentGameHeader();
    if (!joking.username) {
        showUsernameEntry();
        return;
    }

    if (!joking.gamename) {
        showGameMakeOrJoin();
    } else {
        loadCurrentGamenameAndRedraw(joking.gamename);
    }
}

function quitGame() {
    doJsonPost(
        'server/leaveGame.php',
        { gamename: joking.gamename, username: joking.username },
        () => {},
        defaultAjaxError
    );
    joking.gamename = null;
    joking.game = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('gamename');
    stopGameChecking();
    redrawGame();
}

function renderCurrentGameHeader() {
    let buf = '';
    buf += joking.username ? ` <span class='username'>${joking.username}</span> ` : '';
    buf += joking.username && !joking.gamename ? ` (<a href='#' onclick='logout(); return false;'>logout</a>) ` : '';
    buf += joking.gamename
        ? ` | Game ${joking.gamename} (<a href='#' onclick='quitGame(); return false;'>leave game</a>)`
        : '';

    return buf;
}

function showGameMakeOrJoin() {
    window.app.innerHTML = `
        ${msg('Enter existing game code:')} 
        <input id='gamename' type="number" min="0" step="1" onkeypress="setGamenameOnEnter(event);"> <button onclick='setGamename()'>Join game</button></p>
        <h2>or <a href='#' onclick='createGame(); return false;'>Create A New Game</a></h2>
       

    `;
}
function setGamenameOnEnter(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        setGamename();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function showUsernameEntry() {
    window.app.innerHTML = `
        ${msg('Your name:')}
        <input id='username'> <button onclick='setUsername()'>Enter name</button>
        ${renderRules()}`;
}

function setUsername() {
    joking.username = window.username.value;

    joking.username = joking.username.replace(/[^0-9a-z ]/gi, '');

    localStorage.setItem('username', joking.username);
    startup();
}

function logout() {
    delete joking.username;
    delete joking.gamename;
    localStorage.removeItem('username');
    localStorage.removeItem('gamename');
    startup();
}
function setGamename() {
    window.gamename.value = window.gamename.value.toUpperCase();
    joking.gamename = window.gamename.value;
    joinGame(joking.gamename, joking.username);
}

function defaultAjaxError(e) {
    console.log(`Error with Server ${e}`);
    window.debug.innerHTML = `Error with Server ${e}`;
    console.log(e);
}
function createGame() {
    if (!joking.username) return;
    doJsonPost('server/createGame.php', { creatorname: joking.username }, gameCreated, defaultAjaxError);
    // postData('server/createGame.php', { creatorname: joking.username }).then(gameCreated);
}
function gameCreated(data) {
    joking.gamename = data.gamename;
    localStorage.setItem('gamename', joking.gamename);
    joinGame(joking.gamename, joking.username);
}

function joinGame(gamename, username) {
    if (!gamename || !username) return;
    doJsonPost('server/joinGame.php', { gamename, username }, joinedGame, defaultAjaxError);
}

function joinedGame(data) {
    joking.game = data;
    localStorage.setItem('gamename', joking.gamename);
    joking.localstate = {};
    redrawGame();
    startGameChecking();
}

function loadCurrentGamenameAndRedraw(gamename) {
    if (!gamename) return;
    doJsonGet(`server/loadGame.php?gamename=${gamename}`, storeGameThenRender, defaultAjaxError);
}
function storeGameThenRender(game) {
    joking.game = game;
    redrawGame();
}

function redrawGame() {
    const game = typeof joking.game === 'string' ? JSON.parse(joking.game) : joking.game;

    window.topBar.innerHTML = renderCurrentGameHeader();
    window.debug.innerHTML = '';

    window.modalArea.innerHTML = joking.localstate.showModal ? renderModal() : '';

    if (!(joking.game && joking.gamename)) {
        showGameMakeOrJoin();
        return;
    }

    if (joking.lastGameState !== game.state) {
        joking.localstate = {};
    }
    joking.lastGameState = game.state;

    let buf = '';

    joking.gameversion = game.version;

    joking.cardClickHandler = null;

    const aRound = game.rounds && game.rounds[game.rounds.length - 1];
    if (aRound && aRound.msg) {
        buf += `<div><b>${aRound.msg}</b></div>`;
    }

    switch (game.state) {
        case 'GAME_SIGNUP': {
            buf += `
                <h2>Game Code: ${game.gamename}</h2>
                ${msg('Players Currently in Game:')}
                ${renderCurrentPlayerList(game)}`;

            if (game.creatorname === joking.username) {
                buf += `<button onclick='startGame()'>Begin Game</button>`;
                buf += msg('Tell other players the game code, wait for them to join then start the game...');
            } else {
                buf += msg(
                    `<p>Waiting for players to join and then for <span class='username'>${game.creatorname}</span> 
                        to press Begin Game...</p>`
                );
            }
            buf += '<h2>Cards in your hand:</h2>';
            buf += renderPlayerDeck();
            break;
        }
        case 'REG_ROUND': {
            const round = game.rounds[game.rounds.length - 1];
            const { currentjudge } = round;
            if (joking.username === currentjudge) {
                buf += '<h2>You are the judge this round!</h2>';
                buf += msg(`You will pick one of your cards to be the first or second panel 
                            alongside with the deck card. Then other players will pick a final panel
                            and you will decide which one you like the best.`);
            } else {
                buf += `<h2>Waiting for current judge <span class='username'>${currentjudge}</span> to pick...</h2>`;
            }
            buf += `<h2>Deck picked this card:</h2>${renderCard(round.deckpick)}`;

            if (joking.username === currentjudge) {
                joking.cardClickHandler = handleRegJudgeCardClick;
                buf += renderRegJudgePick(round);
            } else {
                buf += `<h2>While you're waiting for <span class='username'>${currentjudge}</span> to pick, check out the cards in your hand:</h2>`;
                buf += renderPlayerDeck(true);
            }

            break;
        }
        case 'REG_PLAYERS_PICK': {
            const round = game.rounds[game.rounds.length - 1];
            const { currentjudge } = round;
            const card1 = round.judgepos === 'before' ? round.judgepick : round.deckpick;
            const card2 = round.judgepos === 'after' ? round.judgepick : round.deckpick;

            // buf += `<pre>${JSON.stringify(joking.game, null, ' ')}</pre>`;
            if (joking.username === currentjudge) {
                // joking.cardClickHandler = handleRegJudgeCardClick;
                // buf += renderRegJudgePick(round);
                buf += '<h2>Waiting for players to pick...</h2>';
                buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(card1, card2, -1);

                if (round.playerpicks) {
                    // buf += msg(`Picked already: ${Object.keys(round.playerpicks).join(' ')}`);
                    buf += msg(`Waiting for: ${renderWaitingFor(round)}`);
                }
            } else {
                if (!round.playerpicks || !round.playerpicks[joking.username]) {
                    joking.cardClickHandler = handleRegPlayerCardClick;
                    const card3 = joking.localstate.pick || -1;
                    buf += `<h2>Here is the setup from judge <span class='username'>${currentjudge}</span>:</h2>`;
                    buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(card1, card2, card3);
                    buf += `<h2>Click or tap a final panel:</h2>`;
                    buf += renderPlayerDeck(true);
                } else {
                    const card3 = round.playerpicks[joking.username];
                    buf += '<h2>Waiting for other players, here is your selection:</h2>';
                    buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(card1, card2, card3);
                    //buf += msg(`Picked already: ${Object.keys(round.playerpicks).join(' ')}`);
                    buf += msg(`Waiting for: ${renderWaitingFor(round)}`);
                }
            }

            break;
        }
        case 'REG_JUDGE_PICK': {
            const round = game.rounds[game.rounds.length - 1];
            const { currentjudge } = round;
            const card1 = round.judgepos === 'before' ? round.judgepick : round.deckpick;
            const card2 = round.judgepos === 'after' ? round.judgepick : round.deckpick;

            if (joking.username === currentjudge) {
                buf += '<h2>Time to pick!</h2>';
                buf += msg('Read each panel aloud, and click or tap which combination you like most:');
                Object.entries(round.playerpicks).map(([player, pick]) => {
                    buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(
                        card1,
                        card2,
                        pick,
                        `onclick="handleRegJudgeFinalPick('${player}')"`
                    );
                });
            } else {
                buf += '<h2>Waiting for judgement!</h2>';
                buf += msg(
                    `<span class='username'>${currentjudge}</span> should read each card and pick a favorite...`
                );

                Object.entries(round.playerpicks).map(([player, pick]) => {
                    if (player === joking.username) {
                        buf += msg('Yours:');
                    } else {
                        buf += msg(`Other player's:`);
                    }
                    buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(card1, card2, pick);
                });
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'REG_END_ROUND': {
            const round = game.rounds[game.rounds.length - 1];
            buf += `<h2>end of round!</h2>`;
            buf += msg(`<span class='username'>${round.winner}</span> is the winner and gets one point!`);

            const card1 = round.judgepos === 'before' ? round.judgepick : round.deckpick;
            const card2 = round.judgepos === 'after' ? round.judgepick : round.deckpick;
            const card3 = round.playerpicks[round.winner];

            buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(card1, card2, card3);

            if (round.nextjudge === joking.username) {
                buf += msg(`You are the next judge!`);
                buf += `<button onclick="startNextRound()">Start Next Round</button>`;
            } else {
                buf += msg(
                    `Waiting for <span class='username'>${round.nextjudge}</span> to start the next round as judge...`
                );
            }

            buf += renderScores();

            break;
        }
        case 'RED_REDRAWS': {
            const round = game.rounds[game.rounds.length - 1];
            buf += '<h2>Deck picked this card:</h2>';
            buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(-1, -1, round.deckpick);

            buf += '<h2>Red Panel Redraw!</h2>';
            buf += msg(
                'The deck has drawn a red panel! Select the cards from your hand that you want to discard and replace with fresh cards:'
            );
            joking.cardClickHandler = handleRedPlayerDiscardClick;
            buf += renderPlayerDeck(true);

            if (!round.playerdiscarded || round.playerdiscarded.indexOf(joking.username) === -1) {
                buf += `<button onclick="handleRedPlayerDiscards()">Discard selected cards</button>`;
                buf += `<button onclick="handleRedPlayerNoDiscards()">(No I love all these cards!)</button>`;
            } else {
                buf += msg('Waiting for other players to discard...');
            }

            break;
        }
        case 'RED_ROUND': {
            buf += '<h2>Red Panel Pick</h2>';

            const round = game.rounds[game.rounds.length - 1];
            const { currentjudge } = round;
            if (joking.username === currentjudge) {
                buf += '<h2>Waiting for players to pick panel 1 + 2!</h2>';
                buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(-1, -1, round.deckpick);
                buf += '<h2>Your hand:</h2>';
                buf += renderPlayerDeck(false);
            } else {
                joking.cardClickHandler = handleRedPlayerCardClick;

                if (round.playerpicks && round.playerpicks[joking.username]) {
                    const [card1, card2] = round.playerpicks[joking.username];
                    buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(card1, card2, round.deckpick);
                    buf += msg('Waiting for other players...');
                } else {
                    const firstCard = joking.localstate.pick ? joking.localstate.pick : -1;
                    buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(
                        firstCard,
                        -1,
                        round.deckpick,
                        `onclick="handleRedPlayerUndoClick()"`
                    );
                    buf += msg(
                        !joking.localstate.pick
                            ? 'You will pick the first and second panels!'
                            : '(click above to undo your selection...)'
                    );
                    buf += `<h2>${!joking.localstate.pick ? 'Pick the first panel' : 'Now pick the second panel'}</h2>`;

                    buf += renderPlayerDeck(true);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'RED_JUDGE_PICK': {
            buf += '<h2>Red Panel Judgement!</h2>';
            const round = game.rounds[game.rounds.length - 1];
            const { currentjudge } = round;

            if (joking.username === currentjudge) {
                buf += '<h2>Time to pick!</h2>';
                buf += msg('Read each panel aloud, and click or tap which comic you like the most');
                Object.entries(round.playerpicks).map(([player, [card1, card2]]) => {
                    buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(
                        card1,
                        card2,
                        round.deckpick,
                        `onclick="handleRedJudgeFinalPick('${player}')"`
                    );
                });
            } else {
                buf += '<h2>Waiting for judgement!</h2>';
                buf += msg(
                    `<span class='username'>${currentjudge}</span> should read each card and pick a favorite...`
                );
                Object.entries(round.playerpicks).map(([player, [card1, card2]]) => {
                    if (player === joking.username) {
                        buf += msg('Yours:');
                    }
                    buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(card1, card2, round.deckpick);
                });
            }
            break;
        }

        case 'RED_END_ROUND': {
            const round = game.rounds[game.rounds.length - 1];
            buf += `<h2>end of round!</h2>`;
            buf += msg(`two points to <span class='username'>${round.winner}</span>!`);

            const [card1, card2] = round.playerpicks[round.winner];

            buf += renderRegPlayerSelection(card1, card2, round.deckpick);

            buf += msg(`<span class='username'>${round.nextjudge}</span> is the next judge...`);

            if (round.nextjudge === joking.username) {
                buf += `<button onclick="startNextRound()">start next round</button>`;
            }

            buf += renderScores();

            break;
        }
    }
    const domApp = window.app;
    domApp.innerHTML = buf;
    console.log(game);

    startGameChecking();
}

function renderWaitingFor(round) {
    const undonePlayers = joking.game.players
        .filter((player) => {
            if (!round.playerpicks) return true;
            if (player.username === round.currentjudge) return false;
            return !round.playerpicks[player.username];
        })
        .map((player) => `<span class='username'>${player.username}</span>`);
    return undonePlayers.join(' ');
}

function msg(m) {
    return `<div class='msg'>${m}</div>`;
}

function renderCard(cardNum) {
    const emptyClass = cardNum == -1 ? 'placeholdercard' : 'emptycard';
    return cardNum && cardNum != -1 ? `<img src="card/${cardNum}.jpg">` : `<div class="${emptyClass}"></div>`;
}
function renderCardWithFrame(cardNum, clickable) {
    if (joking.localstate && joking.localstate.pick === cardNum) return '';
    const onclick = clickable ? `onclick="handleCardClick(${cardNum});"` : '';
    const clickableClass = clickable ? `clickable` : '';
    const clickedClass = joking.localstate.pick && cardNum === joking.localstate.pick ? 'clicked' : '';
    const discardClass = joking.localstate.discards && joking.localstate.discards.includes(cardNum) ? 'discard' : '';
    return `<div class="cardframe ${clickableClass} ${clickedClass} ${discardClass}"
                id="card${cardNum}"
                ${onclick}
                >${renderCard(cardNum)}</div>`;
}
function renderPlayerDeck(clickable = false, isClicked = false) {
    const player = getCurrentPlayerInfoFromGame();
    if (!player) return '';
    const cardbuf = player.cards.map((c) => renderCardWithFrame(c, clickable)).join(' ');
    return `<div class="playerscards ${isClicked ? 'flatten' : ''}" >${cardbuf}</div>`;
}

function handleCardClick(cardNum) {
    if (joking.cardClickHandler) joking.cardClickHandler(cardNum);
}

function renderRegJudgePick(round) {
    const cardIsPicked = Boolean(joking.localstate.pick);
    // let buf = !cardIsPicked ? '<h2>First pick a card to go with it:</h2>' : '<h2>Your selected card:</h2>';
    let buf = '';
    if (!cardIsPicked) {
        buf += '<h2>Now click or tap a card to go right before or after it:</h2>';
        buf += renderPlayerDeck(true, cardIsPicked);
    } else {
    }

    // if (cardIsPicked) buf += msg('(Click card again to undo selection)');
    buf += renderRegJudgeOrderPick(round);

    return buf;
}
function handleRegJudgeCardClick(cardNum) {
    if (joking.localstate.pick === cardNum) {
        joking.localstate.pick = null;
    } else {
        console.log(joking.localstate.pick, cardNum);
        joking.localstate.pick = cardNum;
    }
    redrawGame();
}

function handleRedPlayerDiscardClick(cardNum) {
    if (!joking.localstate.discards) joking.localstate.discards = [];
    if (!joking.localstate.discards.includes(cardNum)) {
        joking.localstate.discards.push(cardNum);
    } else {
        const index = joking.localstate.discards.indexOf(cardNum);
        joking.localstate.discards.splice(index, 1);
    }
    redrawGame();
}
function handleRedPlayerDiscards() {
    const discards = joking.localstate.discards ? joking.localstate.discards : [];
    doJsonPost(
        `server/updateRedPlayerDiscards.php`,
        { gamename: joking.gamename, username: joking.username, discards },
        (game) => {
            storeGameThenRender(game);
        },
        defaultAjaxError
    );
}
function handleRedPlayerNoDiscards() {
    const discards = [];
    doJsonPost(
        `server/updateRedPlayerDiscards.php`,
        { gamename: joking.gamename, username: joking.username, discards },
        (game) => {
            storeGameThenRender(game);
        },
        defaultAjaxError
    );
}

function handleRedPlayerCardClick(cardNum) {
    if (!joking.localstate.pick) {
        joking.localstate.pick = cardNum;
        redrawGame();
    } else {
        doJsonPost(
            `server/updateRedPlayerCard.php`,
            { gamename: joking.gamename, username: joking.username, pick1: joking.localstate.pick, pick2: cardNum },
            (game) => {
                storeGameThenRender(game);
            },
            defaultAjaxError
        );
    }
}
function handleRedPlayerUndoClick() {
    joking.localstate.pick = null;
    redrawGame();
}

function renderRegJudgeOrderPick(round) {
    if (!joking.localstate.pick) return '';
    let buf = `<h2>Now pick an order for your card and the deck's:</h2>`;
    const deckCard = round.deckpick;
    const pickedCard = joking.localstate.pick;
    buf += msg('Your card first:');
    buf += renderOrderPicker('before', pickedCard, deckCard);
    buf += msg('Or Your card second:');
    buf += renderOrderPicker('after', deckCard, pickedCard);

    return buf;
}

function renderOrderPicker(type, card1, card2) {
    return `<div onclick="handleRegJudgeOrderPick('${type}');" class="orderwrap">${renderCard(card1)}${renderCard(
        card2
    )}${renderCard(-1)}</div>`;
}
function renderRegPlayerSelection(card1, card2, card3, onclick) {
    return `<div ${onclick || ''} class="orderwrap">${renderCard(card1)}${renderCard(card2)}${renderCard(card3)}</div>`;
}
function handleRegPlayerCardClick(cardNum) {
    joking.localstate.pick = cardNum;
    doJsonPost(
        `server/updateRegPlayerCard.php`,
        { gamename: joking.gamename, username: joking.username, pick: cardNum },
        (game) => {
            storeGameThenRender(game);
        },
        defaultAjaxError
    );
    redrawGame();
}

function handleRegJudgeOrderPick(judgepos) {
    doJsonPost(
        `server/updateRegJudgeCard.php`,
        {
            gamename: joking.gamename,
            username: joking.username,
            judgepick: joking.localstate.pick,
            judgepos,
        },
        storeGameThenRender,
        defaultAjaxError
    );
}

function handleRegJudgeFinalPick(username) {
    doJsonPost(
        `server/updateRegJudgeFinal.php`,
        { gamename: joking.gamename, winner: username },
        (game) => {
            storeGameThenRender(game);
        },
        defaultAjaxError
    );
}

function handleRedJudgeFinalPick(username) {
    doJsonPost(
        `server/updateRedJudgeFinal.php`,
        { gamename: joking.gamename, winner: username },
        (game) => {
            storeGameThenRender(game);
        },
        defaultAjaxError
    );
}

function showWorking() {
    const domApp = window.app;
    domApp.innerHTML = '<h2>Working...</h2>';
}

function getCurrentPlayerInfoFromGame() {
    for (const player of joking.game.players) {
        if (player.username === joking.username) return player;
    }
    return null;
}

function renderCurrentPlayerList(game) {
    return '<ul>' + game.players.map((p) => `<li><span class='username'>${p.username}</span>`).join('') + '</ul>';
}

function stopGameChecking() {
    if (joking.interval) {
        clearInterval(joking.interval);
        joking.interval = null;
    }
}

function startGameChecking() {
    if (joking.gamename && !joking.interval) {
        joking.interval = setInterval(() => {
            doJsonGet(`server/getGameVersion.php?gamename=${joking.gamename}`, checkGameVersion, gameCheckingError);
        }, 2000);
    }
}

function checkGameVersion(data) {
    // window.debug.innerHTML = `${data.version} ${new Date().getTime()}`;
    if (data.version !== joking.game.version) {
        loadCurrentGamenameAndRedraw(joking.gamename);
    }
}

//TODO
function gameCheckingError(e) {
    console.log('ERRR', e);
}

function renderScores() {
    const scoreForPlayer = {};
    //maybe should be a reducer, too lazy to look that up
    joking.game.players.map((player) => {
        scoreForPlayer[player.username] = 0;
    });
    joking.game.rounds.map((round) => {
        scoreForPlayer[round.winner] += round.isred ? 2 : 1;
    });

    const tableRow = (player) => {
        return player && player != 'undefined'
            ? `<tr><th><span class='username'>${player}</span></th><td>${scoreForPlayer[player]}</td></tr>`
            : '';
    };

    const guts = Object.keys(scoreForPlayer)
        .map((player) => tableRow(player))
        .join('');

    return `<h2>Scores so far</h2><table border="1">${guts}</table>`;
}

function startGame() {
    if (!joking.gamename || !joking.username) return;
    doJsonPost(
        `server/startGame.php`,
        { gamename: joking.gamename, username: joking.username },
        (game) => {
            storeGameThenRender(game);
        },
        defaultAjaxError
    );
}
function startNextRound() {
    if (!joking.gamename || !joking.username) return;

    doJsonPost(`server/startNextRound.php`, { gamename: joking.gamename }, () => {}, defaultAjaxError);
}

function showRulesAndTipJar() {
    joking.localstate.showModal = true;
    redrawGame();
}
function hideRulesAndTipJar() {
    joking.localstate.showModal = false;
    redrawGame();
}

function renderModal() {
    return `
    <div id="myModal" class="modal-backdrop"  onclick='hideRulesAndTipJar();'>
        <div class="modal-content" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
            <span class="close" onclick='hideRulesAndTipJar();'>&times;</span>
            ${renderRules()}
        </div>
    </div>
    `;
}

function renderRules() {
    return `<div>  
</div>`;
}
```

Comment: How your Json looks like?

Comment: Usually this happens if the server responds with a login page, or any other HTML page, instead of the JSON response. You can check the browser's network tab, what the server actually returns.

Comment: Or in other words, you need to ensure that `server/loadGame.php?gamename=${gamename}` actually returns JSON, and not a HTML page, but your question lacks more information.

Comment: There's not a lot to go on. Where in the code is the error appearing? You can use a debugger or lots of console.log statements to find out. What does the JSON file look like, and where is it coming from? There's a lot of code posted, but not enough to get an example working, and a lot seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: You are experiencing this because you don't get a `JSON` but an error from your request to the `php` endpoint. Check your error logs to see if `leaveGame.php` produces errors. Most probably this is your case.

Comment: Can you show us your `doJsonPost` function? I think you use there `JSON.parse(SOME_OBJECT)` and not `JSON.parse(SOME_STRING)`. 

If you test `JSON.parse({"test": "testValue"})` or just `JSON.parse({})` you will see exactly the same error. If you want to use JSON.parse for your object, you must stringify it first: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJECT))`

Answer (score 1):

9 times out of 10 I find that this ***exact*** error message is because the source you are fetching your JSON from is not returning JSON at all. It's not that the JSON is bad, it's that you're not receiving/parsing JSON, you're receiving/parsing something else. A < tag typically indicates you're dealing with HTML.

Right click and view source on this very page on stackoverflow. What's on the first line?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/QAPage" class="html__responsive">
```

That's right, an opening tag, a < symbol, indicating that this document is HTML.

Usually, for me, the cause of this is a redirect from some auth code on my server or something like that. Instead of hitting the server endpoint I was expecting, I receive the HTML for the 403 forbidden page.

Another possibility is that your JSON is bad or is not being returned in JSON format, but you can verify that fairly simply.

I'm not sure how you're fetching your data, that was a lot of code and I'm not 100% comfortable with PHP. However, A good way to test what data you are receiving is to modify whichever portion of your code you're using to fetch that data, or parse it, to log the contents, without the assumption that it is in fact JSON.

In JS, I usually just remove the `JSON.parse()` and instead `console.log(mydata)`

EDIT: If you can modify your code above to show which specific portion above is causing the error (one of the JSON.parse() lines) and show the portion where the data is fetched from whatever location its fetched from, I can help you debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your code. The error means that your json is invalid. This is not because of your configuration or something like that. It's just that your "json file" is a html/xml file and not json.